# Sidebar nav menu submenu is collapsing on page reload in Angular 11

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I have a requirement where I have a sidebar menu and in it, there's a submenu, I want to have it opened once one of its sub-menus is opened.

Following is the code and screenshot,

[image: Sidebar menu]

```
  <div id="sidebar-menu">
                <ul class="metismenu" id="side-menu">
                    <a>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-blue circularBold" (click)="addLayer()">Add Layer</button>
                    </a>
                </ul>
                <ul class="metismenu" id="side-menu" *ngFor="let layer of layerData; let i=index;">
                    <a href="#submenu{{i+1}}" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true"
                        class="bg-dark list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start mt-3"
                        title="Click to expand">
                        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-start align-items-center"
                            routerLink="/dashboard/mainmenu">
                            <h3 class="circularBold menu-collapsed" style="color: #eeeeee;">
                                Layer {{i + 1}}</h3>
                            <!-- <mat-icon></mat-icon> -->
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <div id="submenu{{i+1}}" class="sidebar-submenu"
 [ngClass]="(this.currentRouteURL == '/dashboard/menu1/{{i+1}}' || this.currentRouteURL == '/dashboard/menu2/{{i+1}}'
                || this.currentRouteURL == '/dashboard/menu3/{{i+1}}' || this.currentRouteURL == '/dashboard/menu4/{{i+1}}')? '': 'collapse'">
                        <a routerLink="['/dashboard/menu1', i+1]"
                            class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark text-white text-left">
                            <span class="menu-collapsed">Submenu1</span>
                        </a>
                        <a routerLink="['/dashboard/menu2', i+1]"
                            class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark text-white text-left">
                            <span class="menu-collapsed">Submenu2</span>
                        </a>
                        <a routerLink="['/dashboard/menu3', i+1]"
                            class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark text-white text-left">
                            <span class="menu-collapsed">Submenu3</span>
                        </a>
                        <a routerLink="['/dashboard/menu4', i+1]"
                            class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark text-white text-left">
                            <span class="menu-collapsed">Submenu4</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
#sidebar-container {
    min-height: 100%;   
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Sidebar sizes when expanded and expanded */
.sidebar-expanded {
    width: 240px;
}
.sidebar-collapsed {
    width: 60px;
}

/* Menu item*/
#sidebar-container .list-group a {
    height: 50px;
    color: white;
}

/* Submenu item*/
#sidebar-container .list-group .sidebar-submenu a {
    height: 45px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
.sidebar-submenu {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
}

/* Separators */
.sidebar-separator-title {
    background-color: #333;
    height: 35px;
}
.sidebar-separator {
    background-color: #333;
    height: 25px;
}

/* Closed submenu icon */
#sidebar-container .list-group .list-group-item[aria-expanded="false"] .submenu-icon::after {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
  /* Opened submenu icon */
  #sidebar-container .list-group .list-group-item[aria-expanded="true"] .submenu-icon::after {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
```

Here, I will be having multiple layers with the same submenus where each submenu will open a new page to the right. The issue now is, when I click on any submenus the dropdown area is getting collapsed and I'll have to open them again. I have tried changing `aria-expanded` from false to true but it isn't working.

**Edited**

Now, I have added the following code to HTML

```
 [ngClass]="(this.currentRouteURL == '/dashboard/menu1/{{i+1}}' || this.currentRouteURL == '/dashboard/menu2/{{i+1}}'
                || this.currentRouteURL == '/dashboard/menu3/{{i+1}}' || this.currentRouteURL == '/dashboard/menu4/{{i+1}}')? '': 'collapse'"
```

With the above code, it's working fine now, but the issue now is when I am reloading the page the submenu is collapsing(even having the same route URL). Is there anything that I'm missing

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hey Just wondering I have couple of questions ?
1. Is bootstrap a requirement ?
2. I see you have commented the mat-icon. Correct me if I'm wrong you wanted to use angular material too ? 

Just a suggestion why don't you have close icon something like this `href="javascript:void(0)"` to make the side bar stay until you click the button it will stay. 

if you are using angular material you can use [link](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/examples) @Shinchan

Comment: @MysticGroot 1. it's not mandated to just use bootstrap 2. yeah I tried using angular material, I didn't find angular material side nav attractive as per the design and the issue is not about sidebar collapsing, the dropdown's in sidebar are collapsing